# Example for @DomainEvents and @AfterDomainEventsPublication

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have encountered the @DomainEvents and @AfterDomainEventsPublication annotation  in spring Data JPA Reference Documentation.  But I am not able to find the perfect example to explain about these annotaions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see sample in the original unit tests for  `EventPublishingRepositoryProxyPostProcessor`   [EventPublishingRepositoryProxyPostProcessorUnitTests.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/EventPublishingRepositoryProxyPostProcessorUnitTests.java) by Oliver Gierke in GitHub Repository of [Spring Data Commons](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.domain-events).

Description in base issue of Spring Jira [DATACMNS-928 Support for exposing domain events from aggregate roots as Spring application events](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-928) was useful for me.

**UPDATE**

This is simple and really working example by Zoltan Altfatter:
[Publishing domain events from aggregate roots](http://zoltanaltfatter.com/2017/06/09/publishing-domain-events-from-aggregate-roots)

Answer (score 6):

Here is my example code:

```
package com.peaceelite.humanService;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.springframework.data.domain.AfterDomainEventPublication;
import org.springframework.data.domain.DomainEvents;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
public class SalesmanCustomerRelationship{


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;


/*getters & setters*/

@DomainEvents
Collection<Object> domainEvents() {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
    result.add("Here should be an Event not a String, but, anyway");
    return result;
}

@AfterDomainEventPublication 
void callbackMethod() {
    System.out.println("DATA SAVED!\n"+"WELL DONE");
}

}
```

This is an entity class managed by a spring data repository. Both @DomainEvents and @AfterDomainEventPublication happens after CrudRepository.save() being executed. One thing that is interesting is that @AfterDomainEventPublication ONLY works when @DomainEvents exists.

I'm learning Spring Data reference too, both this question and Dmitry Stolbov's answer helped me a lot.