# How to track the result of transaction in spring?

Tags: spring, transactions

You can imagine I have some service, say it will be money service. Also assume I have one method, that perform actual transfer (Quite mundane example, I know). And I have to return **true** if transaction ended up successfully, and **false**, if it is not. So, here is the think that I do not actually grasp - how do I track the result of transaction in Spring Framework? (May be even for just simple logging purposes) Example of my transfer method is present below. Appreciate any help.

```
@Transactional
    public boolean transferMoneyFromOneAccountToAnother(MoneyTransferForm moneyTransferForm) {
        final UserBankAccount sourceBankAccount = bankAccountRepository.findBankAccountByIdentifier(
                moneyTransferForm.getSourceAccountIdentifier()
        );
        final UserBankAccount targetBankAccount = bankAccountRepository.findBankAccountByIdentifier(
                moneyTransferForm.getTargetAccountIdentifier()
        );
        subtractMoneyFromSourceAccount(moneyTransferForm, sourceBankAccount);
        appendMoneyToTargetAccount(moneyTransferForm, targetBankAccount);
        bankAccountRepository.updateUserBankAccount(sourceBankAccount);
        bankAccountRepository.updateUserBankAccount(targetBankAccount);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do it:

1. You can simply enclose your method call with try/catch block and if there are no exception then your transaction was committed successfully.

   ```
   try{
        transferMoneyFromOneAccountToAnother()

        logger.info("Transacton Done Successfully");

    }catch(Exception ex){
         //transaction failed
         logger.error("Transaction failed")
    }
   ```
2. You can have a method which is annotated with @TransactionalEventListener and listening to your custom event. You can check these links for more understanding of how it works:
   https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events
   [@TransactionalEventListener annotated method not invoked in @Transactional test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712258/transactionaleventlistener-annotated-method-not-invoked-in-transactional-test)